# soundness of peano arithmetic

Tags: logic

Is there a proof (in ZFC for instance) of the soundness of Peano Arithmetic?By "soundness" I mean that all theorems of Peano Arithmetic are true.

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to establish the soundness of peano arithmetic under the mapping $M(0) = \{\}$, $M(S(n)) = M(n) \cup \{M(n)\}$, then just one by one establish that the axioms of PA are theorems of ZFC.

Comment: Yes. The proof in ZFC is a straightforward induction over the standard model of the natural numbers. See Landau's *Foundations of Analysis* or Halmos's *Naive Set Theory* for nice presentations.

Comment: I'm surprised this question was closed as off-topic - it's definitely a question about mathematics, and I'm not sure what additional context is needed (this is a naturally-occurring, interesting question; IMO it doesn't require explicit motivvation). I've voted to reopen.